Why is Stripe complaining about versions after I configured my platform to use the .Net version in my app?
I keep getting these errors (see below) from Stripe when running my app and making Stripe calls. My .Net package version is
<PackageReference Include="Stripe.net" Version="44.0.0" />

and I updated my platform in my Stipe's dashboard to

Why am I getting this error?

Stripe.StripeException: Received event with API version 2022-11-15, but Stripe.net 44.0.0 expects API version 2024-04-10. We recommend that you create a WebhookEndpoint with this API version. Otherwise, you can disable this exception by passing throwOnApiVersionMismatch: false to Stripe.EventUtility.ParseEvent or Stripe.EventUtility.ConstructEvent, but be wary that objects may be incorrectly deserialized.
at Stripe.EventUtility.ParseEvent(String json, Boolean throwOnApiVersionMismatch) in //src/Stripe.net/Services/Events/EventUtility.cs:line 47
at Stripe.EventUtility.ConstructEvent(String json, String stripeSignatureHeader, String secret, Int64 tolerance, Int64 utcNow, Boolean throwOnApiVersionMismatch) in //src/Stripe.net/Services/Events/EventUtility.cs:line 128
at Stripe.EventUtility.ConstructEvent(String json, String stripeSignatureHeader, String secret, Int64 tolerance, Boolean throwOnApiVersionMismatch) in /_/src/Stripe.net/Services/Events/EventUtility.cs:line 88
at Functions.StripePlatformWebhook.Run(HttpRequestData req) in /Users/charles/yogabandy2020/Functions/StripePlatformWebhook.cs:line 61


"You can upgrade your API version in the Developer Dashboard. As a precaution, use API versioning to test a new API version before committing to an upgrade." (see docs], yeah, gotta check on the stripe developer dashboard which api version you are using. make sure both the .net libary and the api version is compatible - don't just slap the latest version of stripe nuget package.

For Stripe's client libraries that are strongly-typed (e.g. java, dotnet), each library version is pinned to a specific Stripe API version  and you won't able to handle both new and old API versions of events at the same time.
Your webhook endpoint is probably set to use a different API version (than that which your code is using). If your webhook endpoint is pinned to a newer API version, your webhook code won’t be able to correctly deserialize the event if you’re using a library that’s pinned to a older API version (and vice versa).
